# Method toGregorianCalendar() cannot be found on java.util.Date type

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

Below is the extract of spring integration flow where in we are getting errors, on some machines the flow test cases are passing but on some systems it's getting failed:

Spring Integration Flow:

```
<integration:chain input-channel="X" output-channel="Y">
    <integration:transformer expression="'{1:F21XXXX}{4:{1XX:' +  new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyMMddHHmm').format(payload.arrivalDateTime.toGregorianCalendar().getTime()) + '}{444:' + payload.statusDetail.etc + '}}'"/>
 </integration:chain>
```

Error:

**ERROR 02/Feb/2017 09:35:08,608 [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#48-1] springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 88): Method call: Method toGregorianCalendar() cannot be found on java.util.Date type
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:185)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:107)**

We are not sure what is missing, we checked Java(1.6.0_35)/maven(3.0.3) and its the same on all the machines. Any help would be apprciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Method toGregorianCalendar() is inside class XMLGregorianCalendar. From the exception it is clear that spring el is trying to call toGregorianCalendar() for Date object. I guess your problem is that, for some test cases you are getting payload.arrivalDateTime as Date object not as XMLGregorianCalendar object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html

Comment: but sometimes the same test case got passed with the same input file and sometime it fails. Also if I build the package and deploy on server the same issue occurs.